# backtick grep call with \s+ throwing "Unrecognized escape \s passed through "

Tags: regex, perl, escaping, system

From my Perl code, I want to execute the system call

```
$grepp = `grep 'output\s+reg' $file`;
```

But I keep

```
Unrecognized escape \s passed through at
```

Could you help me understand this error?

Comment: Actually, the problem here is with `+`: in BRE, you need to escape it, or use `\{1,\}`. With ERE, you may use `+` quantifier as is. Again, ERE is more convenient as this syntax is close to all popular NFA regex engines, that is why I advised using `-E` (POSIX ERE).

Comment: Even when answering your own question, please post the answer as an Answer, not as part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

In double-quoted and other similar string literals such as backticks, `\` is significant to Perl.

`\` followed by a non-word character (such as `\` or another symbol) results in the just the escaped character.

`\` followed by some word characters have special meaning (e.g. `\n` results in a line feed, and so does `\x0A`). When `\` is followed by a word character for which Perl has no meaning (e.g. `\s`), you get that warning because your code isn't forward-compatible. You avoid the warning by making your code forward-compatible by escaping the `\`.

```
my $grepp = `grep 'output\\s+reg' $file`;   # Executes: grep 'output\s+reg' some file.txt
```

---

Beyond the problem you asked about, the code has two major problems.

The first major is the code injection bug. You are inserting text (the file name) into code (the shell command) without doing any form of conversion. This will fail if the file name has any shell meta characters (e.g. space, `(`, `;`, etc.), and a malicious actor can possibly take advantage of this bug to execute damaging commands.

[String::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String::ShellQuote)'s `shell_quote` can be used to avoid this problem.

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote('grep', 'output\s+reg', $file);
my $grepp = `$cmd`;
```

You could also avoid the module and avoid creating a shell using the following:

```
open(my $pipe, '-|', 'grep', 'output\s+reg', $file);
my $grepp = '';
$_ .= $grepp while <$pipe>;
close($pipe);
```

---

The second major problem is that the pattern you provided doesn't mean what you think it does. The regex pattern language used by `grep` by default is quite different than Perl's. You want one of the following:

```
output[[:space:]]\+reg       # Without -E or -P
```

or

```
output\s\+reg                # Without -E or -P. Less portable
```

or

```
output\s+reg                 # With -E or -P
```

So, the following is the final code:

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote('grep', '-E', 'output\s+reg', $file);
my $grepp = `$cmd`;
```

Of course, one has to wonder why you executing the `grep` utility instead of performing the search yourself in Perl.

Comment: On many platforms, `\s` is not supported with `-E`, either.  To portably search for whitespace, use `[[:space:]]` (where of course "portably" here still requires more or less POSIX).

Comment: @tripleee, Thanks, incorporated.

Comment: The comments are still off, you probably want to say simply "with -P" or maybe "with -P or (sometimes if you are lucky) with -E".

Comment: @tripleee, Saying it only works if you're lucky is a far worse description than saying it's a less portable command.